# how to bypass print dialog box using javascript or JQuery..?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Normally `window.print()` is used printing webpage, it trigger print dialog box of browser.

Now my question is how can we bypass this printing dialog box and directly print the web page? is there any way by I could avoid to click on OK button?

Answer (score -1):

Nowdays I believe you could avoid the print dialog from any application by using some cloud printing REST API. So far I only know of PrintNode and Google Cloud Print:

- https://www.printnode.com/docs/api/curl/
- https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appInterfaces

Hope this helps.