# Automatically print on load bypassing the print dialog

Tags: javascript, html

I want it to be printed automatically, skipping the print dialog. Already tried self.print but it's still not working as i wanted to.
Or if there is any alternative for this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload=function(){self.print();} 
</script>
```

Comment: You can't IIRC. It's inbuilt browser functionality.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213660/html-javascript-one-click-print-no-dialogs also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153036/how-to-bypass-print-dialog-box-using-javascript-or-jquery.

Comment: window.onload = function () {

 window.print();
  }